# What does てくんない ending on a verb mean?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, contractions

> 丸尾君、ちょっと辞書かしてくんない？

I think it means "maruo, won't you lend me your dictionary?" But I'm really confused about the verb ending on かす.

A look at some other posts suggests that it might expand to かしてくるのない.
So I would have 'come and lend' (previous sentence says that 丸尾 is sat in a chair, so I suppose 'coming' would be appropriate).

Then I would be left with an 'explanatory の' followed by ない.
I've never seen a のない ending before, and I don't see how 'explanatory の' would be appropriate in this context. Please help me to untangle all of this. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an abbreviated form of 〜てくれない, meaning "to not do 〜 for me".  So 貸してくれない means "won't lend me", but phrased as a question like this (likely with a rising intonation) mean "Hey Maruo, won't you lend me your dictionary for a bit?"